# Quando devo usar um patch?

Tags: git, patch

Uma das features do git é a utilização de patches.
Em que situações um patch deve ser utilizado?

Eu li que patches foram pensados para hotfixes. Contudo, não consigo entender porque eu faria um patch ao invés de simplesmente fazer um push com a correção ou um pull request.

Seria o caso de quem corrigiu o bug ter permissão para clonar o repositório, mas não ter permissão para push nem pull requests?

Comment: De uma olhada aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279602/what-is-a-patch-in-git-version-control e também aqui http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/patch-workflows

Comment: Existe todo um mundo de lista de e-mails, IRC etc onde pessoas trocam patches. Bem antes de *pull requests*  e toda esse movimento de "codificação social" surgir era assim que grandes projetos *open source* funcionavam... E ainda é assim que parte deles funcionam até hoje, *old habits die hard*.

Comment: De uma olhada no que o  [Linus Torvalds escreveu nesse pull request](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/17). Enquanto a conversa por lá é sobre "como o mecanismo de *pull requests* do GitHub está quebrado", veja que a discussão vai longe. Enquanto isso os iniciados trocam *patches* na lista de e-mail de forma perfeitamente aceitável :).

Comment: Eu vi que na verdade, mesmo usando patches, os contribuidores podem fazer um pull request para que o patch seja aceito. O que você falou de ser um método antigo faz todo sentido. Porque o próprio patch já vem formatado para ser enviado via e-mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os patches são utilizados quando se quer enviar um commit do Git via e-mail, tanto que o Git tem utlitários até para fazer o envio.

Isto tem a ver com a prática dos desenvolvedores do kernel Linux de trocar patches e discutí-los via e-mail e listas de discussão. Alguns projetos imitam esse modus operandi. Pessoalmente, prefiro uma ferramenta de revisão tipo Gerrit.

Comment: Mas porque enviar um commit via e-mail ao invés de fazer um pull request?

Comment: Pull request pressupõe algum sistema tipo GitHub que tenha uma interface para lidar com pull request. O pessoal que desenvolve Linux, BlueZ e outros projetos preferem não adotar um sistema deste tipo.