# Como fazer cherry-pick de um outro repositório git?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Eu queria saber como que eu faço para copiar um commit de um projeto para o outro.

Eu pensei que seria somente `git cherry-pick 76a99b8c395ebbc40a07c04dc9e0d9fefc9982cd`, mas isso é só se eu estiver dentro do mesmo projeto, quando quero passar de uma branch para outra.

Como que eu faço de um projeto para o outro?

Comment: Cherry pick não rola. O que você pode tentar é gerar um patch desse commit e aplicar no outro repo. Essa pergunta pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148309/quando-devo-usar-um-patch

Comment: Você quer levar a mudança de um projeto para outro, é isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso adicionando o outro repositório Git como [remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

```
git remote add projeto-b ~/projetos/projeto-b
git fetch projeto-b
git cherry-pick <commit1>..<commit2>
```

Comment: Isso vai depender se os repositórios tem a mesma origem... Mas, se eles tem a mesma origem, não é que o commit está sendo enviado para outro repo, e sim para o remote deste